# Get a consistent vector of list element names

Tags: r

A list with no names returns NULL for its names:

```
> names(list(1,2,3))
NULL
```

but add one named thing and suddenly the names has the length of the list:

```
> names(list(1,2,3,a=4))
[1] ""  ""  ""  "a"
```

because this is now a *named list*. What I'd like is a function, rnames say, to make any list into a named list, such that:

```
rnames(list(1,2,3)) == c("","","")
identical(rnames(list()), character(0))
length(rnames(foo)) == length(foo) # for all foo
```

and the following, which is what names() does anyway:

```
rnames(list(1,2,3,a=3)) == c("","","","a")
rnames(list(a=1,b=1)) == c("a","b")
```

My current hacky method is to add a named thing to the list, get the names, and then chop it off:

```
rnames = function(l){names(c(monkey=1,l))[-1]}
```

but is there a better/proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach that feels slightly cleaner is to assign names to the list:

```
x <- list(1,2,3)
names(x) <- rep("", length(x))
names(x)
[1] "" "" ""
```

Turning it into a function:

```
rnames <- function(x){
  if(is.null(names(x))) names(x) <- rep("", length(x))
  return(x)
}
```

Test cases:

```
x1 <- rnames(list(1,2,3))
x2 <- rnames(list(1,2,3,a=3))
x3 <- rnames(list(a=1,b=1))

names(x1)
[1] "" "" ""

names(x2)
[1] ""  ""  ""  "a"

names(x3)
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Close enough :) my rnames returns the names rather than the renamed list, but the renamed list might be useful. I was hoping there might just be a function to convert a list to a named list. Couldn't find one...

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
rnames <- function(x) {
    if(is.null(names(x)))
      character(length(x))
    else
      names(x)
}
```

It handles the `list()` and no names cases; and it doesn't do anything if there are already names.

Answer (score 1):

The names are in an attribute named ... names:

```
> lis2 <- list("a", "b")
> attributes(lis2)
NULL

> if(is.null(names(lis2)) ) {names(lis2) <- 
                         vector(mode="character", length=length(lis2))}
> lis2
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

> names(lis2)
[1] "" ""

> attributes(lis2)
$names
[1] "" ""
```